# Android Activity and layout issue

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I believe my problem is in connecting xml views properly with my activity. I thought simple_list_item_1.xml was the default way by Android to name the layout in question but perhaps I'm wrong somewhere...

I've been following this tutorial and now I have no errors in my code and the app runs on my phone (the instructions are great overall, but it leaves the layouts largely to the imagination):

https://guides.codepath.com/android/Loading-Contacts-with-Content-Providers#using-cursorloader-to-query-the-contentprovider

But when I run my app it looks like this:

[image]

In design mode item_contact.xml looks like this:

[image]

I'm posting my exact project code of the relevant files. Any help, I would much appreciate it (this may be linked to the problem - that lighter shade of grey rectangle at the bottom of my app?)

**MainActivity.java:**

```
package com.example.chris.contactswithcursorloader;

import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager;
import android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader;
import android.support.v4.content.Loader;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    // ... existing code ...
    private SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;

    // Defines the asynchronous callback for the contacts data loader
    private LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> contactsLoader =
            new LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>() {
                // Create and return the actual cursor loader for the contacts data
                @Override
                public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
                    // Define the columns to retrieve
                    String[] projectionFields = new String[]{ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
                            ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
                            ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_URI};
                    // Construct the loader
                    CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(MainActivity.this,
                            ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, // URI
                            projectionFields, // projection fields
                            null, // the selection criteria
                            null, // the selection args
                            null // the sort order
                    );
                    // Return the loader for use
                    return cursorLoader;
                }

                // When the system finishes retrieving the Cursor through the CursorLoader,
                // a call to the onLoadFinished() method takes place.
                @Override
                public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
                    // The swapCursor() method assigns the new Cursor to the adapter
                    adapter.swapCursor(cursor);
                }

                // This method is triggered when the loader is being reset
                // and the loader data is no longer available. Called if the data
                // in the provider changes and the Cursor becomes stale.
                @Override
                public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
                    // Clear the Cursor we were using with another call to the swapCursor()
                    adapter.swapCursor(null);
                }
            };
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.item_contact);

        setupCursorAdapter();

        // Initialize the loader with a special ID and the defined callbacks from above
        getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(CONTACT_LOADER_ID,
                new Bundle(), contactsLoader);

        // Find list and bind to adapter
        ListView lvContacts = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvContacts);

        if(lvContacts != null) {
            lvContacts.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }

    // Create simple cursor adapter to connect the cursor dataset we load with a ListView
    private void setupCursorAdapter() {
        // Column data from cursor to bind views from
        String[] uiBindFrom = { ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_URI };
        // View IDs which will have the respective column data inserted
        int[] uiBindTo = { R.id.tvName, R.id.ivImage };
        // Create the simple cursor adapter to use for our list
        // specifying the template to inflate (item_contact),
        adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                this, R.layout.item_contact,
                null, uiBindFrom, uiBindTo,
                0);
    }

    public static final int CONTACT_LOADER_ID = 78; // From docs: A unique identifier for this loader. Can be whatever you want.

}
```

**item_contact.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView android:id="@+id/lvContacts"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </ListView>

    <!--android:background="#ff3399"-->

</LinearLayout>
```

**simple_list_item_1.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/tvName"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/ivImage"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView_callnumber"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.chris.contactswithcursorloader" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Just FYI RecyclerView is typically preferred over ListView.

Comment: @AdamNelson Not really.  For anything this simple recycler is more work and overkill.

Comment: Never assume data will load based on the "preview" window of Android Studio. If there were no data in your adapter, you would have seen an empty screen as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                this, R.layout.item_contact,
                null, uiBindFrom, uiBindTo,
                0);
```

The layout should be the layout of the item, not the main layout for the activity.  You want simple_list_item1 here.

Comment: Nice one. That was quick. So quick StackOverFlow are making me wait 5 mins before I can accept right answer. To go about searching this list of contacts with softkeyboard and edit text, would you have any suggestions/ reading to look at?